# Need recommendations for KVM with mixed PS/2 and USB ports

Tags: keyboard-video-mouse

I'm looking for a KVM that can support machines with PS/2 ports and machines with USB ports in the same switch.

I have a Dell 1800 (PS/2) and a Dell 1900 (USB with adapter) and the 1900's KB and mouse  will not work with the new KVM I got, though it does work with an adapter (PS/2 mouse & KB in, USB out) connected directly to the server.  I have checked with the manufacturer that they will not support my configuration.

What KVMs support both PS/2 and USB?

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 1):

We use Linkskey KVMs in our server room.  They seem to work well and don't cost an arm and a leg.  Here's the 8-port version of what we have:  [LINKSKEY LKV-9308](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817402020)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [combo](http://www.iogear.com/solutions/kvm/?view=consoleCombo) models of KVM from IOGEAR. They all support both USB and PS/2, depending on the cable type used. Different sizes from 2 to 16 ports. I've had good experiences using their products and haven't run in to any compatibility issues yet.

Comment: IOGear swears up and down that mixed ports are not supported by any of their products.  Facepalm moment is that we have one of IOGear's rack-mounted 8 port PS/2 units and *it* works with a USB dongle.
I must have been stupid for thinking that this would work with a new switch.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a recommendation, but a suggestion that you try a different USB adapter.  Our older Raritan Paragon KVM didn't seem to work with several USB adapters, but works perfectly with some.

Here is a [USB adapter](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812101117) that seems to work with all PS2 KVMs that I have worked with.

Answer (score 0):

We use the 8 port version of the [Belkin OmniView PRO3](http://catalog.belkin.com/IWCatProductPage.process?Product_Id=379141).